# Zend Framework right practice multiple forms

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, amazon-s3, transloadit

I'm working on a page with some forms in it. I've made a wireframe to clarify my question.
[image]

As you can see I have multiple file uploads. To upload a file to my amazon s3 bucket I use [transloadit](https://transloadit.com/).
Transloadit works like this:

```
<form id="uLogoForm" action="/quiz/design" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="logo">
</form>
```

When I select a file and press "Select" transloadit will automatically upload it to amazon s3 and a post will be submitted where I save the link to the uploaded image in my database.

As you can see I have already 3 forms on my page, because I have three file uploads ... .

Besides that I have other input fields and a selected value that needs to be saved when I press "Save" on the bottom of the page.

What's the best practice for doing this? One form with multiple subforms, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing the point, but since there is 1 save button, why not set `triggerUploadOnFileSelection` to `false`, and add 3 `<input type="file">` tags inside a single form? Transloadit can handle multiple file uploads with one form.